# Calculation of $\int_{\partial B(\frac 1 2, \frac 3 4)} \frac{dz}{z(z^2-1)}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I'm having hard time with calculation of

$$\int_{\partial B(\frac 1 2, \frac 3 4)} \frac{dz}{z(z^2-1)}$$

**My work so far**

Hint that I was given was to use partial fraction decomposition. i.e. to find such $A, B$ and $C$ that:

$$\frac{1}{z(z^2-1)} = \frac{A}{z} + \frac{B}{z-1} + \frac{C}{z+1}$$

From my calculation I derive $A = -1, B = \frac 1 2$ and $C = - \frac 1 2$.

Could you please give me a hint what I should do next? Which theorem should I use?

Comment: Make a drawing of your circle : the interior poles are $0$ and $1$...

Comment: Sorry, I get $A=C=1/2$ and $B=-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far, it is shown that
$$
\int_{\partial B(\frac 1 2, \frac 3 4)} \frac{dz}{z(z^2-1)}=
-\int_{\partial B(\frac 1 2, \frac 3 4)} \frac{dz}{z}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{\partial B(\frac 1 2, \frac 3 4)} \frac{dz}{z-1}-\frac{1}{2}\int_{\partial B(\frac 1 2, \frac 3 4)} \frac{dz}{z+1}
$$
Next, using the fact that
$$
\int_{\partial B(a,r)}\frac{dz}{z-z_0}=\left\{
\begin{array}{cc} 
2\pi i & \text{if} & z_0\in B(a,r), \\
0 & \text{if} & z_0\not\in \overline{B}(a,r), \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
we obtain that
$$
\int_{\partial B(\frac 1 2, \frac 3 4)} \frac{dz}{z(z^2-1)}=
-\pi i.
$$

Comment: Good method, up to the computation of $A,B,C$. The residue theorem also gives the answer without decomposing the fraction. If $f$ is a meromorphic function and if $a$ is a simple pole of $f$, then the residue of $f$ at $a$ equals the limit of $(z-a)f(z)$ as $z \to a$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem